# Imagen en base 64 en correo

Tags: html, python, html5, email

Estoy intentando mandar en un correo una plantilla html. Todo eso ya lo hice correctamente, el problema es que el src de la imagen está en formato de base64 y cuando abro el correo se ve la imagen vacía, pero si lo abro desde el explorador de archivos se ve correctamente. ¿Qué puedo hacer?
La imagen a fuerza debe estar en base64.

Comment: Tal vez esto te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/q/9110091/13419694

Comment: Hola Roberto, presiona [edit] y agregar un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

El formato es sencillo y estándar.

En la etiqueta `src` debes poner los valores `data:tipoMIME;base64,`  seguido de la imagen misma en, codificada en base64.

Te dejo un par de ejemplos:

```html
<div>
  <p>De la Wikipedia</p>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Punto rojo" />
</div>
```

```html
<div>
  <p>SO Logo</p>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEA
    CAYAAABccqhmAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAA
    B3RJTUUH5gsOEjUcMlT9+gAAAAZiS0dEAAAAAAAA+UO7fwAAE+dJREFUeNrtnfl7leWZgPu/TFwogkvrUsfBtjO2dUStY+1q
    Z9Rx2jrViuN0uTq1NYQkIAQCguwgq7Kj7GvCGkNYwpYEshBQ2QLTa+bK2Zdn3uc5mQppEs75zneSnJz7h/s3SOB8572/933e
    Z/mS/Pd5AYCCZO6X+BAAEAAAIAAAQAAAgAAAAAEAAAIAAAQAAAgAABAAACAAAEAAAIAAAAABAAACAAAEAAAIAAAQAAAgAABA
    AACAAAAAAQAAAgAABAAACAAAEAAAIAAAQAAAgAAAAAEAAAIAAAQAAAgAABAAACAAAEAAAIAAABAAHwIAAgAABAAACAAAEAAA
    IAAAQAAAgAAAAAEAAAIAAAQAAAgAABAAACAAAEAAAIAAAAABAAACAAAEAAAIAAAQAAwJkp/XS/z0JklebuDzQABQSCTO1Uh4
    5asSfO9xidUuErnWxueCAKAgFv+pTRKc813pLLlTOt8ukuCs0ZJoruazQQAwdGm3rX60qlICFQ9LZ3GRW/x/k6L4NgkvfUmS
    F0/wOSEAGHJcP2dv+PDqMdJZOvyLhd+NyLYydxRo5fNCADCUFn/syAoJzX/O3vS9LX6j/B6JHV1puwU+OwQA+R7l1y1/9TQJ
    VH6974X/l6NAkQTnPC2Js7v5/BAA5PXiP39IIut+LYEJX0lv8f8/JXdKeNVrkvysns8RAUC+Ej/5kQSnP2ZR/owEoJSNkOjO
    iSJXm/ksEQDkJdfaJLqrQgLj781cAI7ApIckdng5+QEIAPL2GHDptIRXvy6dY2/3JIHQ7Ccl0bKPzxIBQN5K4FyNBGd8x5MA
    lPCHr4h0tPBZIgDIV2JHV0mg/G5vEigdbslDfI4IAPKVq80S2VXRlfqbuQSClaMkXr9G5Dr5AQgA8vMo8Fl9Kh7gVQLznpVE
    y16ShBAA5G0RUNMOCWkR0K0yAnvLD1jzH+QHIADI67TgQ0tSxUBergbH32eZhdJBfgACgPw8Clw9K9Ftpe6NPsybBCY/IomG
    bXyWCADylitNElzwQ89Xg8GZoyXpfgafJQKAPK4VCE77e28SKC6S8KrXkQACgJzT0SLxkxvcW/uM//GAumUSmPSg53hAbO90
    koQQAOQ0aFe7SILv/oNEt5b4HoHXVOHI5mIr/vF0FJj+LYmf+Ij8AAQAOanoc4tLm3batZ1bpOFVv5JE2wF/rwbbayW05EX3
    OzzUC4y93f3dF6zBKM8LAYCfC7Nlr4QW/ujmQp6SYRJa8H2JN+3w763rfk68cZvtMjzFA9y/KaK7E+IBCAD8C9CFl7/c+/l7
    yiPu/L7U1/O35Qdk2jzkhiSh2MH5ZAkiAMh68bs3aXjdr2/u2tuTBMrvlui+mXaO92snENnwB8+lwxpMpLU4AoBsm3jsnpx2
    vn5g/D0WxEuer/OpXuC4hBY97710eMkLkvz0GM8RAUDmtEusZqF14snozVs+0mr2U4U6PsQDTm30Hg8ovSslpKtneZ4IADKO
    +GvjjuIiT2fw4Nx/8qebb0eLRPdMd2K5x9tRoOJrEvtkIVeDCADSj/jvS/Xt97j1/svim3CfxI+tzrqZZ/LKGYlsfEs6xw33
    lh/gRKY7CSSAACAdATRXS2jpi7aFzl4CX5FY9TRJfp7dmC+9iQgt/mfPQcHwsn+VxIXDPF8EAGlJoO2ARNb/xnNWXncJRDb8
    lyX5ZHM1Fz+1SQKVj3q+Goxs+pNlM/J8EQCk2bUnurvCbb2/nLUEOstGSmjZy5Jo3eddAm7xRg/McbuAO7yJSEeNHVvJs0UA
    kFG9/v7Zdp7PWgIaHJw5OqsbAstLWDPGe+nwe4+7ncgnPFsEAJnkA8SPr5fgrNGe377dk3RsyIfH6zldwMH53/fWSmzs7RJe
    +iKtxBAAZLzwzux0i+cldyQYlr0EJt4v0V0TvS1EzQ84vs57/wB3HIlsGSvJy408VwQAGW3B3dvXgoMeu/l2r+HXNOOkl+Dg
    1WaJVk+VwDtf9XYUmPJ3qfqFa608VwQAGUng4kn3Bi2RTq/DPboN+rAS3tbMy4r1alFLkj23Fp/9dFdQkmeKACCzxXe5IZWh
    57GDT/dzeXD2U54yBy0eMOPbnn+vVjmyC0AA4DU4WL9WgrOe9Jyg8wVFEtBtec2CjIOD8TO7PKcKayBRpxYzdRgBgOfMwT22
    jfflhsCd6SPbyruCg2nGBTQ/YPcUCXhMWgq8c7/EbNQYSUIIALwdCT49IuGVv/Qnfbj8bgmvfVMSGZQVp+IBr0lnyR2edgHB
    uc+4I0gVzxIBgPfMwWMS2fy2904+3ZKGQktfSj9Id73dYgihec96+33jviyRNW/Y/4FniQDAqwQunZaYBgcnP+xLcFAXdPzk
    x2nHJGKHFtu0IG/XkvdKdO8MWosjAMg6OHhyQ1c/gduyk0BxV3Bw/xwrC76lgK61SkRHjZWN9Jil+JBlPVI6jACGFvqF7ucg
    l7bnDmnKrg9JQ53l97iFXebO+sfT6h8QXvGK93qBGY9b+THfGwQwdLbmF464t+gsSTRt79dpuprlF175qj9JQ+OGSWTdf6a1
    OLX02HMrMe0fsO5NWosjgKGzJY/tm2l35cFZT1htfrxhi/RX22yVj/bmC0x8wIe4wB0SXv4zJ7Idt/y9sbolnlOFVVia6MTV
    IAIYEll7wVlP3RTxDk77puXhJ87u6pfzrgYHo24HkmmT0V5vCOY+Y0lIfS1QfYNHto7zeAQpkuD0xyR+Yj3fIQSQ38SPrug5
    GOfeplqVp+flROPW1JY3lzK41mo7D+vqk3Vw8Da7aYjWzO8zc1B3HxYP8PL73N8JLf6pJM4d5HuEAPKUjhYJLfhBWudr69hz
    fJ0kPz3qRJC71Nhk634JatNRPzoNuZ8R3V5uBUq9xgOatktwztMeJFCUyhK0rsIcBRBAPr79T26QQAZXYjrcI/zBzyXm3qwW
    bMvJF79dEm0HLXNPf58f+QKRj37nfub+Xm9AYp+873Y7D2aWHTjtGxKtquxTLggABvHbvzWVnuuhUEeDZ+FFz1vNfa6y45IX
    DtudvedAXbedgHYyjp/e0qO0kleb7Rox3TkHNvTUh5bmCAAGrkjHLYbg1G9k2bTjXgnN+17qTfjZ0RwEBxskdnCedPqUPqxt
    yyw42EN1nwYib3kc0lsGtzOxFGSSgRBA/l79ube/Dtcsyb59l701S4fbvXp0xwQr/PG1hl6Dg3pU0RRePzIHJz6Qmg7cw79R
    S4eDU0b1/PcmPWhVhWz5EUD+v/0bt0lw5j9mv/h7KZ/VwFuiucquGP3JJ2i3arzQwh96ngD0V3X+O3voOWj1At3yA/Racf5z
    1meQtz4CGAJn/2ZruOlLlL2vINnUr0tk01uphWMi8EFcrfslvOYNKwnOWlRu1xJZPSbVhvyGhZ28dMqGhFj/AEdY/0wbV30I
    YAiV5YZX/CJ3i79bBD7gRKC9+SxolkbBzq17CxyVqAbs/Lgh0ODgop9aPOTGuIDe7UfWvWndgFQIfG8QwJDaASQatkjk4993
    9ewryr0I3Bk6WDlKwh/8zIlgpcjV7ESgLbttIMn4e31JH9aBIHHt+nPDkcPyHTqI8iOAoVr9597GyXM1Etn8x9SZN+u+fWnu
    CPTmYOGPLAPRrtG85hJ0tEjsyArbYXgaU949qUcHldaS1IMACvFY8PkJu3PXN2HqfF3UL0eE0JzvWqNPSyry2GgjcWaX28b/
    xJeYRmDKqFRFJN8JBFB4tFt5bnT3ZIu2+5KFl+45fP5zEq2eluq756EDr04r1uBgZ9ldWeUJ6DUmOwAEwI6g/ROJ7Z1uc/J8
    OWenOwRk7jNuEY63K8RM6w20GUhka4n7OSM83VpooNKPICUggCESJ2izrXm8bpmEP/y5Lx190xPBXZaxF9n4lrUUz+SNbMHB
    qsqMB5KElrxoHYp47ggA/koE5yR58ZTdHOiOwBJxinMdIyiyo4Fm/6W6/NSmLQLN69dkHi3WSSeWYenBpzeT5IMAIC0ZNFdL
    eO0bEpj6aG6TibrFCcJrxkjCLVRLxU1DBtYGfNHzvTf80KtJJ4mY3kbwbBEAZCYCHQeu7cOsu29p/4jAqhBXvSbxw8tT9/S3
    2g2cP5waENrDyHL9Wdbmm6AfAoAsRNCwVaLbSi2A1187Aq030KSiWM3CW4pAjy+W9DThvpve/toOLJnhnEFAANAT7tydcEeD
    2L73rDy4X44Fmrwz8UFry6W/V3MZ+pKAzQesSA0kCX3wb1b+y7NDAOBzmbG+keM183NWbdhj/z/taDzzCROBXGvpJTh4VmJ1
    SyW8+ldWVMTzQgCQ436Dml+vxTbW8jvbWv5MxojvrpBk24GMR4kDAoCciGC1bbsDlaN8GROeVjmyNijZXpqacYAIEAAMMFea
    rBIwsv43qTv6/ig+0qu+dx+T6JZii1HwHBAADHSa8aUGiZ/aKNGt41I7gv64NXBHkDj3/QigsAJybZJoqU6Nybo6CHPcr5yx
    bjxagJNrEQRnP2U7EL4XCKCg3rR6V25b7fKRbhGMlshHv5V47SLbDutUHMuqs/PxAKbBXm+3f4dG8DWSHygf6W85svv/a2dh
    vhMIoMBaf9VLYNo3e02t1SBZePnLEt1WLvHDyywfXq/HkhdPDFh2nDYRje151/rua7KPHzcHursg4QcBFBzauz7ttt8ld9r1
    mdbl6z25dvXVkVeJ05vcTqHO3zbf6fQl+PSoxA7MsSrEbNuWRXdN4vuAAAqPeO3i7JJrJj4gwRnfsuYgOkEotVP4QJI6DNNj
    9x4vItDgnUrpplTetN/+j1qzEL4PCKDg0EIdX7PtykbY21inCWkrr/Dq1925fUaqeUdOhdBuxxK9OdDfGRifvggim9+WJE0+
    EEAhYsU5OU62saQed8zQt3No3rMmnfihxdZsVGMQlm9vnXX9GQ5iqcZt+yWy8Q8SmPy3fRYfabNQSwLiu4AACi4A6N56nT4M
    z/Bevz/MHR++7c7wv5DoznckfuRDm0akXXesz74PQUbtVhTZ9Meebw50IvD631LwgwAKNADoFltPNfADhtsp6Hlc24HbwI2d
    EyVW+777d25NlfN6aAT6Ra7DXvt5NjasbERXd99HJOakw3cBARQk2uiiX3LusxHCxPutDbl27YmsGdO1U+gKMmbYEFT/vF5h
    6s2BtggPr3y1z/JgQABDGp1n1z/Vdz4ODCkbKYFJD1l+Qmj+96wXYGz/bOv7n/Y1pLYsO19nDGhyEwLggxiw839HiwRnPZk/
    i7+3pqCawagBxtLhlhQUev/HEt1cbPEEbVuuNwNJTe/taGWxIwD4IjhWZ4vFMukGUxzA9yDjd2yrr23AdfCo1jyoGJjnhwBo
    z9W03c7DWgYbXvGKpdYGNS24bMTQFILuFCpHWXswRnshALix0OZygwXI4ic/lljNfIluL3NS+HcJzXlaAhO+2g89/vt3Z6A3
    IDx7BAC9duhptiQdTZFNNG6XeN0Sd7b+k0XjrWlmfzTqyBXld0vyKpl/CGAQ0nmxWc431kvrqaNpE77cD0U4mpTT0WIBNU3S
    SbbstYm9kbVvWh29xhI0Qm9Zd4NcDtqRON3/d8e5hoyexaWWUxLrYIYAAvDIldZTsn9PlezcsSMtdjn+58LAN7FIXjop8dMb
    JVY11R0dfmkpxnpVp1d2AYspDJ4jhGYGpvv/aqw/lPazUI7X1UjocgvfZQRQWALoqbefjvHWFts6yVcn7+itg6b+6rSdgcw/
    0L4GCAABIIB+jSm440N7rTUUiR1aLNHdFTY7MLTgB5aS2+tsvhzcBGTS7x8BIAAEkKOYgrb40sIfvZuPH1sl0V0V1txDjw65
    Gh8WnP6YBTcRAAJAAIPsKjIVZGw0MWipsDb5iGwZawU82mPAYgkWZLzDc0xBm5bolScCQAAIIM+uJS2mcHCeRD7+nbUl07d5
    YPLDNvIr3ZuHaNWUjBqTIAAEgAAGI1riq7uEY6ttUWtRUHjJv0hw1hMSqPhaz+nNbvegfz6TmgAEgAAQQL5kM2riUtN2iR9e
    LtHqaRLZ8HsJLXkhFVMovcsmDdn8gwx+LgJAAAggL2m3q0jtCJQ4s1Pi9Wsdq2wEOAJAAAigIHcJ5zIuCUYACAABFDAIAAEM
    OQFoL4B4/Rq7ey8kEk07Mx4BjgAQwJATgPYA0Lr4QMVDBYXlAFgbMASAAApYANHqqUO3C1BfVYCLfpLqBoQAEAACQAAIAAEg
    AASAABAAAkAACAABIAAEgAAQAAJAAAgAASAABIAAEAACQAAIAAEgAASAABAAAkAACAABIAAEgAAQQJ4WA2kzzuY9jqqCQrsS
    p6YEIwAEQDkwIAAEgAAAASAABAAIAAEgAEAACAABAAJAAAgAEAACQAAIAAEgAASAABAAAkAACAABIAAEgAAQAAJAAAgAASCA
    gROAcqGpXq63N4LPXGtvkGOHDiIABDC4BQCDBwSAABAAAuC7jAAQAAIABIAAEAAgAASAAAABIAAEAAgAASAABIAAEAACQACA
    ABAAAgAEgAAQAAJAAAgAASAAFhMCQACFR+RKq/z5QhPFOHnK/352VhLX2vkuIwAAQAAAgAAAAAEAAAIAQAAIAAABAAACAAAE
    AAAIAAAQAAAgAABAAACAAAAAAQAAAgAABAAACAAAEAAAIAAAQAAAgAAAAAEAAAIAAAQAAAgAABAAACAAAEAAAIAAAAABAAAC
    AAAEAAAIAAAQAAAgAABAAACAAAAAAQAAAgAABAAACAAAAfAhACAAAEAAAIAAAAABAAACAAAEAAAIAAAQAAAgAABAAACAAAAA
    AQAAAgCAQS+A6+dnAEAB8ufzP/4/zjN4gXk7oK4AAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6Y3JlYXRlADIwMjItMTEtMTRUMTg6NTM6MjgrMDA6
    MDDveP/oAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOm1vZGlmeQAyMDIyLTExLTE0VDE4OjUzOjI4KzAwOjAwniVHVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" 
    alt="so logo" />
</div>
```

Comment: Lo probaste en un cliente de correo??? Porque yo entiendo que el problema está ahí, no en la estructura de la URI (que al parecer eso lo tiene resuelto)